# Re-Use PHP Function rather than duplicate

Tags: php, function, csv

Hopefully someone can assist, I currently coding pages for a game manual and i'm using two functions I found here, one to pull text/formatting from a html file and the other to pull data from a CSV file and insert it into a table. If I have more than one section to include in the page I have been duplicating the code. An example of the result can be found [here](https://www.triborn.net/manual/manual.php?page=farming)

As you can see the page shows three sections and this is the result I want. What i'm wondering is if there is a more efficient way than how I am currently doing it which is by copying the code and just altering the variables for every file I want to import? As you can see the variable name is set by the page name. Below is the code I am using.

```
//function to display csv as table
    function csvimport($filename, $header = false)
    {

        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        echo '<table id="subman">';
        //display header row if true
        if ($header) {
            $csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle);
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($csvcontents as $headercolumn) {
                echo "<th>$headercolumn</th>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        // displaying contents
        while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($csvcontents as $column) {
                echo "<td>$column</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

I then use the following to select the CSV file to use and display as a table.

```
csvimport("$data", "true");
```

defined by the variable $data

```
//get page name from link or use manual as default
    $page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'manual';

    //combine page name with suffix and set page variables
    $data = "{$page}.csv";
```

I use similar for the html as shown below.

```
$myfile = fopen("$text", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile, filesize("$text"));
    fclose($myfile);
```

So I can get multiple files to display in order I copy the code and add these variables.

```
$data = "{$page}.csv";
$data2 = "{$page}2.csv";
$data3 = "{$page}3.csv";
```

Hopefully I have explained myself and what I am trying to ask.

Thank you all in advance for reading :)

Comment: There is an addage you may want to learn _If it aint broke, don't fix it_

Comment: @RiggsFolly hehe thats true I guess

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how modern web frameworks work. They separate the [view, the model and the controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). The **model** is the logical architecture of your application, the **controller** is the code to route and render each page, and the **view** is all the html output and the styling.

Viewing your code I would separate first the view. Here I have done a first step of what I'm saying. It is only a first step, I recommend you  to [learn a few (a lot of) programming concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453342/php-code-tier-and-html-view-tier-separation), to use composer components, to look deeply at one of the million php (micro)[frameworks](https://coderseye.com/best-php-frameworks-for-web-developers/) or to [roll your own](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html). There is a lot of oportunities nowadays to do [php the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

**Separation of the controller and the templates**

index.php

```
function csvimport($filename, $delimiter = ',') {

  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $output = [];

  while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, $delimiter)) {
    $output[] = $csvcontents;
  }
  fclose($handle);
  return $output;
}

function tpl($fileName, $data = false) {

  $rendered = "";
  if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    ob_start();
    extract($data);
    require($fileName);
    $rendered = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
  }

  return $rendered;
}

$data['header'] = true;
$data['csvcontents'] = csvimport(CSV_FILE, ';');

echo tpl('table.tpl.php', $data);
```

table.tpl.php

```
<table id="subman">
  <?php
  $first = true;
  foreach ($csvcontents as $row) :
    if ($first) :
      $first = false;
      if ($header) :
        $tag = 'th';
      else:
        continue;
      endif;
    else:
      $tag = 'td';
    endif;
    ?>
    <tr>    
      <?php foreach ($row as $column) : ?>
        <<?= $tag ?>><?= $column ?></<?= $tag ?>>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

The index has a few functions to read csv and render any template and the template holds all the html output. This is only a first approach, far for being a production ready code, use at your own risk and [never trust user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711582/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-filtered-get-variable)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that has given me a lot to think about. I still have a lot to learn. Cheers !